# In SSRS Need Optional Union Query or Equivalent

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I've inherited an SSRS report that doesn't work correctly. The report is a meta report of a document management system. FWIW, this is a monthly destruction report -- certain documents to be destroyed per retention policy. The kicker in this application is that there are special "stack_location" values that represent certain content status, e.g. 86/86/86 meaning document checked out but not returned. Any given document can have only one stack location, or one special stack location value.

The basic query returned all the appropriate documents. The original designer, then created a filter list that excluded all the special values. This is as intended. However, the designer apparently assumed these special value exclusions could be toggled by clicking on a radio button in an options section. This, of course, does not work. Indeed, the whole approach seems off.

I think I need a default query that includes an AND NOT IN ('86/86/86', '96/96/86'...), then somehow optional unions with the special values. I am completely at sea, however, on how to accomplish this.

It seems it would be relatively straight forward if I were just using VB, or C#, to write different dynamic queries based on the value of a radio button. I am required, however, to use SSRS, technology I'm only vaguely familiar with.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the radio button's value to the query, then as you suggested, include in your where clause something like
AND (StackLocation  NOT IN ('86/86/86', '96/96/86'...) OR @MyRadioButton = 'SomeValue').